# C++ strange function behavior

Tags: c++

I've been working in C++ a bit lately and only using a small subset of the language (I'd call it C with classes) so I've been messing around trying to learn about some of the other features of the language. To this end I was going to write a simple JSON parser, and almost immediately hit a road block I cannot decipher. Here's the code:

```
//json.hpp
#include <cstring>


namespace JSON
{
    const char WS[] = {0x20,0x09,0x0A,0x0D};
    const char CONTROL[] = {0x5B,0x7B,0x5D,0x7D,0x3A,0x2C};

    bool is_whitespace(char c) {
        if (strchr(WS, c) != nullptr)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    bool is_control_char(char c) {
        if (strchr(CONTROL, c) != nullptr)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here's main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "json.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for(int i=0; i < 127; i++) {
        if(JSON::is_whitespace((char) i)) {
            cout << (char) i << " is whitespace." << endl;
        }
        if(JSON::is_control_char((char) i)) {
            cout << (char) i << " is a control char." << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm just trying to check if a char is a valid whitespace or a valid control character in JSON.

```
 is whitespace.
 is a control char.
     is whitespace.

 is whitespace.
 is whitespace.
  is whitespace.
, is whitespace.
, is a control char.
: is whitespace.
: is a control char.
[ is whitespace.
[ is a control char.
] is whitespace.
] is a control char.
{ is whitespace.
{ is a control char.
} is whitespace.
} is a control char.
```

I've been staring for awhile now. I don't even know what search term to put into Google to describe this error (or feature?)... any explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The functions defined in header must have `inline` keyword, otherwise you cause undefined behaviour due to multiple definitions if two different `.cpp` files include that header

Comment: *I'd call it C with classes* - You would have liked the early '80s.

Comment: You never null terminate your search strings

Comment: In C++ style you could write `const std::set<char> WS = { ' ', '\r', '\n', '\t' };` and the search function `return WS.find(ch) != WS.end();`

Comment: @clcto You're correct. Damn it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you read the requirements on [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr)

> ```
> const char* strchr( const char* str, int ch );
> ```
>
> **`str`**   -   pointer to the **null-terminated byte string** to be analyzed

Whereas you are passing in:

```
const char WS[] = {0x20,0x09,0x0A,0x0D};
const char CONTROL[] = {0x5B,0x7B,0x5D,0x7D,0x3A,0x2C};
```

Neither of those is a null-terminated byte string. You *could* manually add a 0:

```
const char WS[] = {0x20,0x09,0x0A,0x0D, 0x0};
const char CONTROL[] = {0x5B,0x7B,0x5D,0x7D,0x3A,0x2C, 0x0};
```

Or, better yet, not actually rely on that behavior:

```
template <size_t N>
bool contains(const char (&arr)[N], char c) {
    return std::find(arr, arr+N, c) != (arr+N);
}

bool is_whitespace(char c) { return contains(WS, c); }
bool is_control_char(char c) { return contains(CONTROL, c); }
```

In C++11:

```
template <size_t N>
bool contains(const char (&arr)[N], char c) {
    return std::find(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), c) !=
        std::end(arr);
}
```

Comment: Heh, lesson 1: stop using C-style arrays and C library functions :)

Comment: I would also like to add that he's comparing to `nullptr` rather than null, but the documentation on `strchr` uses `null` in its examples.

Comment: Thank you. Will look into the suggested C++ syntax.